# What is `... on` doing in this GraphQL?

Tags: graphql

I am trying to mimic what some GraphQL does, but I do not have access to be able to run the original. It is of the form:

```
query {
  dataSources(dataType: Ais) {
    ... on AisDataSource {
      messages(filter: {broadcastType: Static}) {
        ... on AisStaticBroadcast {
          field1
          field2
```

(I have ommitted the closing parentheses).

It is my understanding that `... on` is either to include a fragment (none here), or to choose between alternatives (but these are nested). So is this query wrong, or is there more to `... on`?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This

```
{
  user {
    ... on User {
      id
      username
    }
  }
}
```

and this

```
{
  user {
    ...UserFragment
  }
}

fragment UserFragment on User {
  id
  username
}
```

are equivalent. In both cases, you are using a fragment. In the first example, we simply refer to the fragment as an [inline fragment](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Inline-Fragments).

When requesting a field that return a *composite type* (an object, interface or union), you must specify a *selection set*, or one or more fields for the return type. Since fragments must include a *type condition* (the `on` keyword plus the type name), they can be used to specify different selection sets depending on the type that's actually returned at runtime.

```
{
  user {
    ...RegularUserFragment
    ...AdminFragment
  }
}

fragment RegularUserFragment on RegularUser {
  id
  username
}

fragment AdminFragment on Admin {
  id
  username
  accessLevel
}
```

All we're saying is "if the type at runtime is this, then return this set of fields". If any of the fields inside the fragment also return a composite type, then those fields also have to specify a selection set for — that means additional fragments can be used inside *those* selection sets.

Comment: Superb, many thanks! ! I must have missed that in the tutorial I read.