# How can I use subclasses or subtypes on graphql?

Tags: inheritance, graphql, quarkus

For short, I'd like to have something similar to this response in my Quarkus microservice: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61527915/6999690

### Entities

I've the following entities annotated with persistence API in order to integrate with [h2](/questions/tagged/h2) database

#### Publication

```
package org.javapro.model;

import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Inheritance;
import jakarta.persistence.InheritanceType;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public abstract class Publication {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    public Long id;
    public String title;
    public String author;
    public int pages;
    public String publisher;
}
```

#### Book

```
package org.javapro.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Book extends Publication{

    public String Isbn;
}
```

#### Magazine

```
package org.javapro.model;

import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Setter
@Getter
@SuperBuilder
public class Magazine extends Publication{
    public String Issn;
}
```

### Repository

I'm generating Database access layer or repository trough spring-data-jpa

```
package org.javapro.repository;

import org.javapro.model.Publication;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface PublicationRepository extends JpaRepository<Publication, Long> {
}
```

### Service

```
package org.javapro.service;

import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.javapro.model.Publication;
import org.javapro.repository.PublicationRepository;

import java.util.List;

@ApplicationScoped
public class PublicationService {
    PublicationRepository publicationRepository;

    public PublicationService(PublicationRepository publicationRepository) {
        this.publicationRepository = publicationRepository;
    }

    public List<Publication> findAll() {
        return publicationRepository.findAll();
    }
}
```

### GraphQL resource

In order to register operation at the endpoint I'm using microprofile and more concretely smallrye.

```
import jakarta.enterprise.context.ApplicationScoped;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.graphql.GraphQLApi;
import org.eclipse.microprofile.graphql.Query;
import org.javapro.model.Publication;
import org.javapro.service.PublicationService;

@GraphQLApi
@ApplicationScoped
public class PublicationResource {

    PublicationService publicationService;

    public PublicationResource(PublicationService publicationService) {
        this.publicationService = publicationService;
    }
    @Query("publications")
    public List<Publication> getPublications() {
        return publicationService.findAll();
    }
}
```

### Problem

I'd like to do a query as follows:

```
{
  publications{
    author
    id
    ... on Book{
      isbn
    }
    ... on Magazine{
      issn
    }
    pages
    publisher
    title
  }
}
```

However I'm getting the following error instead

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Validation error (InvalidFragmentType@[publications]) : Fragment cannot be spread here as objects of type 'Publication' can never be of type 'Book'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 5,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "extensions": {
        "classification": "ValidationError"
      }
    }
  ],
  "data": null
}
```

¿How can I modify my code to get rid of the error?

### attempts

I just read this article and will try to do the same in Java, I'll keep you posted once done https://nelsondominguez.hashnode.dev/inheritance-in-graphql-when-and-how-to-use-it

Update: no luck there mates